# the coding problem in server

Tags: php, localhost

```
$fp = fopen("http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/PoliticsNews?format=xml","r")
    or die("Error reading RSS data.");
```

The above coding working correctly in localhost;;;

but in server display "Error reading RSS data."...

i dont know why....

anybody please explain me...

i am waiting...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason could be that [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) might be disabled *(quoting)* :

> This option enables the URL-aware
> fopen wrappers that enable accessing
> URL object like files.

You can check using the `phpinfo()` function, to see if it's enabled or not.

If it's not enabled, you'll have to use another solution to send the HTTP request that fetches that remote content.

Using [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) might be a solution, for instance ; see [`curl_exec`](https://www.php.net/curl_exec) for a quick example, and [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for a list of all possible options.

Here's what a simple request would look like, though :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/PoliticsNews?format=xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$feed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This will get you the content of the feed in `$feed` -- but check the manual page of `curl_setopt` : there are so many options that going through the list cannot be a bad idea.

Still, as a precaution, before going this way, you might want to check if curl is enabled, is the output of `phpinfo()`...

Answer (score 2):

Try making sure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled on the server. If it isn't, the call to fopen will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely that the server is configured [so that fopen() can not open a remote URL](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php). You might want to try [Simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) for parsing feeds, it takes the pain out of it.

Answer (score 0):

rubbish talks of "possible reasons" and not a single suggestion how to get a real reason.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of the script to see what goes wrong.

Comment: Umm.. rubbish? Yeah, that'll go far. ini_set() doesn't always work, btw :)

Comment: I'm not talking of "always". I'm talking of now. in *this* case it'll work, as we can see this code has no syntax errors.

Comment: if allow_url_fopen isn't enabled, there's a good chance ini_set() is listed in disable_functions. I fail to see how pointing the OP to phpinfo() and docs that describe allow_url_fopen is rubbish?

Comment: because it's guessing. programmer shouldn't guess. programmer should debug.